# Can you automate the new product registration in iTunes Connect (In App Purchase)?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am considering using In App Purchase for our iPhone app. But since we will offer a larger quantity of content items (>10 video items each day added), I would like to automate the new product registration in iTunes Connect. 
Is this possible ?
If not: how long does it typically take before Apple approves a new registred product in iTunes Connect ? Since the content looses quickly it's 'freshness' (news broadcasts...), it is crucial to be able to have new content available ASAP.
Would you recommend using In App Purchase for this scenario or would you recommend developing our own payment & account system ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to automate it, unless you develop your own script (in AppleScript, for example, to operate safari and I am not sure if it will work as expected.

A new app will be reviewed and approved typically in 7 days. In-app purchases will go live when the app is approved.

In-app purchases can operate in two ways:

1. you include the content inside the app
2. you put the content on your severs and include the mechanisms to make the magic work. When the user buy the app, Apple server will communicate with yours and vice-versa, and a signal must be sent to Apple servers, during the process, so they will know the content was delivered. You will have to read the docs, as this is too complex to explain here.

Comment: As of iOS 6 Apple is willing to host in-app. purchases.

Answer (score 1):

I automated the input of a large number of in-app purchases using the Firefox extension `iMacros`. The free version is absolutely sufficient for this.

You have to create a CSV file containing all the data, then record the workflow in iTunes Connect and press start!